# How to get ProgramFiles paths?

Tags: c#

I have weird problem.

I`m using windows 7 enterprise sp1 64 bit.

I need to take Program files and Program files X86 directories path for my project. This is what I've done:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86);
```

but both of these lines returns Program files X86 folder.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Is you app targeted to 64bit?

Comment: I'm guessing he wants to retrieve both the 64bit and 32bit ProgramFiles folder.

Comment: Are you running a 32bit application?

Comment: I`m not sure, When i will be at work i will check it. I think my ap trageted to 32 bit. I didn`t know that this is the reason.
thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The result depends on what platform is your project targeting. If you target x86, then both `Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles` and `Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86` will return the same path.

For example to get the actual path as a `string` use

```
string programFiles = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86);
```

Comment: This is nitpicking, but they don't actually return a path. They return an enum value that needs to be used with Environment.GetFolderPath() to get the path.

Answer (score 82):

This will work for x86, x64 or Any CPU configurations:

```
string programFiles = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramW6432%");
string programFilesX86 = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles(x86)%");
```

Because using the environment variable `ProgramW6432` will always return Program Files folder whereas `ProgramFiles` will vary depending on your application compilation options.

Comment: Great answer! One caveat: this environment variable was added in Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2, so if you're unlucky enough to still need to support earlier versions of Windows then you may need an alternate solution. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384274(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. You shouldn't be forced to change the target architecture just to get a path...

Comment: In my Windows 10 x86 this does not work. The variable will return exactly "%ProgramW6432%" and "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" respectively, instead of "C:/Program Files ...".

Comment: @masphei:  Only x64 Systems have dual paths for Program Files folder, your x86 Windows CAN'T install x64 programs, therefore it has ONLY one path.

Answer (score 3):

`Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles` should return the x86 folder for a 32-bit application and Program Files for a 64-bit application on 64-bit Windows. Check your project configuration settings.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Configuration Manager (Build -> Configuration Manager) in Visual Studio to change the targeted platform.

In the platform column see if x64 is available. If it is not, click on the drop down and select "New". You will then be able to add the x64 as a target platform. Debug again, and you will see that `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)` will return `C:\Program Files`.

Answer (score 1):

If your program is 32 bit, this alway return x86 folder

Comment: how would you get program files folder if running 32 bit app on 64bit machine?

Comment: @f1wade, for Program Files => `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramW6432%")`
for Program Files X86 => `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles(x86)%")`

Answer (score 0):

David's answer will work only for Windows 7 and above as per Dan Nolan's comment.

Here is a solution that will work for x86, x64 or Any CPU configurations AND will work for older versions of Windows.

```
string ProgramFiles = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles%");

if (ProgramFiles[ProgramFiles.Length-1].Equals(')'))  // If ProgramFiles(x86)
    ProgramFiles = ProgramFiles.Substring(0, ProgramFiles.Length - 6);
```

Essentially, just remove the (x86) if it is there, when it shouldn't be.

OR:

Looking at this registry value seems like a reliable solution too:
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir

Answer (score 0):

The approach that you have taken is absolutely correct. We just need to tell the compiler to not prefer a particular build platform

Its as simple as

**Go to Visual Studio > Project Properties > Build > Uncheck "Prefer 32 bit"**