# How can I determine if my executing assembly is within the Program Files special folder?

Tags: c#

How do I determine if my executing assembly is being called within the special folder Program Files or from with Users folder?

I know I can do a contains "Program Files" on the location property but would that suffice or is there another way?

```
MessageBox.Text = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location;
```

I need to use a condition in program based on where program was installed. If it was installed in Program Files I know it was a machine install and if in a user folder it was a user-based install.

Comment: Only you can tell us if that suffices. We don't even know why you need to know if it's located there in the first place. A more robust solution would be to use [SpecialFolders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netcore-3.1) and see if your assembly location begins with the special folders paths you're interested in.

Comment: The location doesn’t necessarily contain “Program Files”, you can get the location from `Environment.GetFolderPath()`

Comment: You can get the path to the "Program Files" directory: [How to get ProgramFiles paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12710958/215552)

Comment: If you need to distinguish then why not making it explicit? Make checkbox in installer.

Comment: @Sinatr, not in the requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this ?

```
        string programFiles = System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramW6432%");
        
        var location = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location;

        var isProgramFiles = location.StartsWith(programFiles);
```